# swift 3 - How to close a page (tab) inside a webview

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, swift3

In a viewcontroller I am using this code to open a local html file

```
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: webFrame, configuration: config)
self.webView?.uiDelegate = self as? WKUIDelegate 
self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self 
self.webView?.scrollView.bounces = false
self.container!.addSubview(webView!) 
let testUrl: URL! = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "assets") 
self.webView!.loadFileURL(testUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: testUrl)
```

Debugging by safari in the menu Developer> Simulator appears the open page (index.html) It happens that every time I leave this viewControler and return is added in the menu Developer> Simulator a new page (index.html, index.html, ...) . I believe that new pages are opened in new tabs
In the function I use to exit this viewController I use this code

```
self.webView?.removeFromSuperview()
self.container.removeFromSuperview()
```

The objects are removed but the pages are not, does anyone know how to remove them?